# how can show blob file in mvc page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, blob

I uploaded some different blob type (.pdf, .xls, .gif. .png ...) in database.
now I want to show its icon (by type) and read its blob content in my view page, for example if this is a pdf file show pdf icon and by double clicking on that file open

please help me, thank you

Comment: Which specific part of this you are having difficulties with implementing? Querying a database? Streaming a file into the response? Showing a list of available entities in the view?

Comment: how can I get extension file type, in this code: var extension = Path.GetExtension(SourceFileName).ToLower(); SourceFileName is phisical address of file, can I pass it <BLOB>?

Comment: If you only habe a BLOB, then you probably have no filename. And _Path.GetExtension_ works on filenames. So no, you can't pass it a BLOB.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do consists of two parts: a view page that displays a link (with the icon) for each file and a separate action (in one of your controllers) that delivers the actual file contents.

The easiest approach is probably if you analyze the file type when you upload the files into the database and then store the file type in a separate column in the database. For most files, you can derive the file type from the first few bytes of the files (see [Magic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)).

The action of the controller responsible for delivering the file content to the user is straightforward to implement. Based on some ID of the file, it loads it from the database into a byte array and returns it as a *FileContentResult* instance.

To create a link to the file (in your view page), just use *Html.ActionLink* or a similar function with the controller name, action name and the ID of the file.